# How to find twitter handles in a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

If I had the following:

```
NSString *tweet = @"Shoutout to @somebody and @somebodyElse for your help on this one   #shoutouts";
```

How would i go about finding the range of the twitter handles (eg @somebody)??

I want to make them bold in my Attributed String which is the next step.

Bonus points if you can help me find the # hash tags as well, but I assume its the same algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NSRegularExpression` class,

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Than trying using this online tool to build Regex,

http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

I tried this and it seems like you can build a good one,

[image]

**SAMPLE CODE - NOT TESTED**

```
NSString *yourString = @"Shoutout to @somebody and @somebodyElse for your help on this one   #shoutouts";
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression         
    regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\@\S+|#\S+"
    options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
    error:&error];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){
    // your code to handle matches here
}];
```

About test in online tool!

[image]
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks heaps for the detailed answer! I owe ya a beer!

Comment: Ohhh u'r from Melbourne too! My prospect of getting beer is higher now, remember my owl picture, we might run into each other somewhere on swanston on friday night! And I am always out of cash so that would be a great treat! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend.